# Can an iOS push notification selectively replace a prior notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using iOS push notifications. In Android you can set up to 4 notification keys and then using these keys you can have notifications replace prior notifications if they have not yet been read/seen by the user.

Do iOS push notifications also allow you to selectively replace prior notifications? (E.g. using a common notification key) or do they always "rack up" and cannot be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9):

> Quality of Service
>
> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
>   the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered
>   to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored.
>   If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each
>   new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This
>   behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as
>   coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that
>   were being stored for it are discarded.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such mechanism in place in iOS.
After sending a push notification you have no control over it anymore.